# django - annotate a field and return the queryset including that field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been at this for 3 hours.

```
last_prices = (
                UsStockPriceModel.objects
                    .filter(ticker__in=tickers)
                    .order_by('ticker', '-last_date_time')
                    .distinct('ticker')
                    .values('ticker', 'last_price')
            )

last_close_dict = {price['ticker']: price['last_price'] for price in last_prices}

# tried, error annotate got a non-expression
dca_orders = self.request.user.dca_orders.all().annotate(
                last_close_price=DecimalField(default=0.0)
            )
# tried, standalone and with above statement
for instruction in dca_orders:
                instruction.last_close_price = last_close_dict.get(instruction.ticker, 0.0)
```

I have tried using `Case` and a lot of other things. For some reason the `last_close_price` field is never returned. It is not a part of the model, I need the field only in specific cases.